# как вставить из autocompletetextview текст в recyclerView

Tags: kotlin, recyclerview

Всем привет , как сделатть так чтобы у меня есть Autocomplete texview, я туда ввожу название фильма и у меня из сервера imdb приходит филльмы , при наборе названия какого нибудь фильма Autocomplete выходит подсказка. Мне нужно чтоб эти фильмы которые я ввожу отобразить в RecyclerView

class MainActivity : BaseActivity() {

```
private val adapter = RecyclerAdapter()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    RetrofitBuilder.getService()
    //90b2f7c2

    search.doAfterTextChanged {
        if (!it.isNullOrEmpty() && it.toString().length > 2)  // если текстбольше 2 букв
            getSearch(it.toString())  // то делаеем запрос
    }
}






   private fun getSearch(text: String) {

  RetrofitBuilder.getService()?.getCinema("90b2f7c2",text)

      ?.enqueue(object : Callback<CinemaSearchModel>{
          override fun onResponse(
              call: Call<CinemaSearchModel>,
              response: Response<CinemaSearchModel>
          ) {
              if (response.isSuccessful && response.body() != null){
                  val arrays = response.body()?.search?.map { it.title }?.toTypedArray()
                  //map создает list из Strings , нам необходим array а не list , поэтому toTypedArray() конвертирует стринги в array
                  arrays?.let {
                      search.setAdapter(

                          ArrayAdapter(applicationContext,
                              android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,
                              it
                          )
                      )
                  }

              }
          }
          override fun onFailure(call: Call<CinemaSearchModel>, t: Throwable) {
              Toast.makeText(applicationContext, t.localizedMessage , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
          }
      })
} }
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1196981/265051

Comment: @Cypher спасибо вам большое!!!