# Организация поиска в RecyclerView

Tags: java, android

Я использовал RecyclerView для отображения списка с элементами. Хочу реализовать поиск по этому способу, но желательно наиболее простым и действенным способом. разобраться в тех примерах что нашел в интернете не получилось, увы, т.к. они ещё сложны для меня (пока что новичок).

Код адаптера:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext ;
    private List<Anime> mData ;
    RequestOptions option;


    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context mContext, List<Anime> mData) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mData = mData;

        // Request option for Glide
        option = new RequestOptions().centerCrop().placeholder(R.drawable.loading_shape).error(R.drawable.loading_shape);

    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view ;
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.anime_row_item,parent,false) ;
        final MyViewHolder viewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view) ;
        viewHolder.view_container.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent i = new Intent(mContext, AnimeActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("id",mData.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getID());
                i.putExtra("title",mData.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getName());
                i.putExtra("description",mData.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getDescription());
                i.putExtra("author",mData.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getCategorie());
                i.putExtra("mindescript",mData.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getMinDesc());
                i.putExtra("rating",mData.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getRating());
                i.putExtra("previewimgurl",mData.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getImage_url());
                i.putExtra("modsize",mData.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getFileSize());

                mContext.startActivity(i);

            }
        });

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.tv_name.setText(mData.get(position).getName());
        holder.tv_category.setText(mData.get(position).getCategorie());
        holder.tv_min_description.setText(mData.get(position).getMinDesc());

        // Load Image from the internet and set it into Imageview using Glide

        Glide.with(mContext).load(mData.get(position).getImage_url()).apply(option).into(holder.img_thumbnail);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView tv_name ;
        TextView tv_category;
        TextView tv_min_description;
        ImageView img_thumbnail;
        LinearLayout view_container;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            view_container = itemView.findViewById(R.id.container);
            tv_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.anime_name);
            tv_category = itemView.findViewById(R.id.categorie);
            tv_min_description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.minidescript);
            img_thumbnail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);

        }
    }

}
```

P.S Хотелось бы, чтоб поиск был снизу ( пока не разобрался, опять же )

Главный активити:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lstAnime = new ArrayList<>() ;
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerviewid);
    jsonrequest();



}

private void jsonrequest() {

    request = new JsonArrayRequest(JSON_URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

            JSONObject jsonObject  = null;

            for (int i = 0 ; i < response.length(); i++ ) {


                try {
                    jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i) ;
                    //тут у меня некий код по типу такого
                    R1 r = new R1() ;
                    r.setID(jsonObject.getString("id"));
                    lstAnime.add(anime);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }

            setuprecyclerview(lstAnime);

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });


    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
    requestQueue.add(request) ;


}

private void setuprecyclerview(List<Anime> lstAnime) {

    RecyclerViewAdapter myadapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this,lstAnime) ;
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(myadapter);

}
```

Comment: вот есть подобный вопрос - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1192503/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d1%80-%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5/1192657#1192657

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример того как решить эту задачу с помощью паттерна `Observer`. У нас "тупая" вьюха, а вся логика фильтрации во `ViewModel`.

[image: ezgif-com-gif-maker-2.gif]

`Activity`:

```
class SearchViewActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var viewModel: SearchViewModel

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_view)
    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(SearchViewModel::class.java)

    viewModel.filteredItems.observe(this) {
        recycler_view.adapter = SearchAdapter(it)
    }

    search_view.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
        override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
            query?.let { viewModel.filterItems(it) }
            return true
        }

        override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
            newText?.let { viewModel.filterItems(it) }
            return true
        }
    })
}
}
```

`ViewModel`:

```
class SearchViewModel : ViewModel() {

private val items = MutableLiveData<MutableList<Item>>().apply {
    value = mutableListOf(
        Item(1, "Один"),
        Item(2, "Два"),
        Item(3, "Три"),
        Item(4, "Четыре"),
        Item(5, "Пять")
    )
}
val filteredItems = MutableLiveData<MutableList<Item>>().apply {
    value = items.value
}

fun filterItems(query: String) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val filteredList = mutableListOf<Item>()
        items.value?.map {
            if (it.title.contains(query, true)) filteredList.add(it)
        }
        filteredItems.postValue(filteredList)
    }
}
}
```

`Adapter`:

```
class SearchAdapter(private val items: List<Item>) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchAdapter.SearchViewHolder>() {

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) = SearchViewHolder(
    LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_date, parent, false)
)

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SearchViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.title.text = items[position].title
}

override fun getItemCount() = items.size

class SearchViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    val title: TextView = view.date_title
}
}
```

`Item`:

```
data class Item(
val id: Int,
val title: String
)
```

`R.layout.activity_search_view`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".recycler_search.SearchViewActivity">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
    android:id="@+id/search_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/search_view"
    tools:listitem="@layout/item_date" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```