# Реализация строки поиска по массиву в спинере

Tags: java, android

Есть спинер, который в виде выпадающего списка выдает список людей, содержащихся в массиве. Каким образом можно реализовать поиск по словам в этом самом спинере / списке ? (Поиск типа: вводишь первые буквы - выдает все совпадения, которые начинаются с этих букв).

Массив:

```
public synchronized void fillNameStocks() {
        String[] tempArr = new String[arrayListMols.size() + 1];
        tempArr[0] = "Не выбрано";
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayListMols.size(); i++) {
            tempArr[i + 1] = arrayListMols.get(i).Name;
        }
        MyArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new MyArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_item, tempArr);
        spinnerNamesOfMols.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinnerNamesOfMols.setSelection(0);
        spinnerNamesOfMols.setOnItemSelectedListener(new SpinnerActivity());
    }
```

Класс со спинером:

```
class SpinnerActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
            Log.w("Список", "Выбрана позиция : " + pos);
            indexOfIdToSendNextAct = pos - 1;
        }
    }
```

**UPD:**  Разметка спинера:

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner4"
        android:layout_width="271dp"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:spinnerMode="dialog"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView19"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView19">
        

    </Spinner>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел в Google библиотеку, которая позволяет просто изменить одну строку (напишите `com.toptoche.searchablespinnerlibrary.SearchableSpinner` вместо `Spinner`) и добавить соответствующую зависимость в проект, и все, проблема решена.

[Ссылка на либу](https://github.com/miteshpithadiya/SearchableSpinner)

Answer (score 1):

Это легко реализовать с помощью `AutoCompleteTextView`

[image: ezgif-com-gif-maker-1.gif]

Создаем массив слов в strings.xml:

```
<string-array name="names_array">
    <item>Александр</item>
    <item>Алексей</item>
    <item>Антон</item>
    <item>Борис</item>
    <item>Владимир</item>
    <item>Владислав</item>
    <item>Иван</item>
    <item>Илья</item>
</string-array>
```

`Activity`:

```
class SortActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sort)

    val adapter = ArrayAdapter(
        this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
        resources.getStringArray(R.array.names_array)
    )
    autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adapter)

    button.setOnClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(this, autoCompleteTextView.text, LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
}
```

`R.layout.activity_sort`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">

<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:hint="Начните вводить имя" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Ок" />
```

Comment: задумка так то хорошая, но тут массив (массив не строк, а именно массив с данными) получает данные из внутренней ДБ, откуда закачка с сервера идет.

Comment: @СергейБеляков А что мешает достать имена из объектов и также с ними работать?

Comment: а как его к спинеру подключить?

Comment: @СергейБеляков в смысле вам надо знать какое имя выбрал пользователь и потом например изменять данные в бд? Тогда можно сделать поиск по RecyclerView https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1196981/265051

Comment: @СергейБеляков Да и спиннер можно гормально подключить. в чем проблема то? Вы же знаете какое имя пользователь выбрал и по нему изменяете данные

Comment: Нет, идея в чем - спинер в любом случае должен быть (сейчас дополню код разметкой), и необходимо при нажатии на данный спинер - высвечивался спиннер с именами, и над ним окошечко, чтобы можно было набрать например текст и он выводил совпадения.

Comment: @СергейБеляков не понимаю. в моем примере же так же есть editText куда вы вводите и спинер. Что не так?

Comment: я не смотрел еще ваш пример

Comment: @СергейБеляков сформулируйте точнее что вас не устраивает в предложенном мной варианте

Comment: не то что не устраивает, скорее мне не понятно. Вот есть спиннер, есть адаптер откуда спинер получает данные. Вот как можно сюда встроить как раз поисковое окошечко с такой логикой?  На первом скрине (в этом посте) присваивается адаптер, с переменной tempArr, которая и содержит данные.

Comment: @СергейБеляков делайте так же как сделал я. Только вам нужно создать список имен и таким же образом как я добавляете его в ArrayAdapter третьим параметром: val adapter = ArrayAdapter(
        this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
        names(ваш список)
    )   И обрабатываете нажатие также. Не вижу проблемы

Comment: скажу так - имена берутся из внутренней бд, в которую скачка из внешней идет. Имена заранее неизствены и их порядка 1.5к . Подействует такой способ?

Comment: @СергейБеляков вам в таком случае нужна следующая логика. Вы вводите несколько символов и во вью модели дергаете метод, передавая в параметры эти символы. Этот метод делает запрос в бд или сервер с которого получаете данные и фильтруете по этим символам. Затем отфильтрованый список сетите в `MutableLiveData` на которую подписана вьюха и выводит этот список в спинер. Вот здесь можно посмотреть как взаимодействовать с ViewModel: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1196981/265051

Comment: хорошо, спасибо, гляну

Comment: нашел более простой и изящный способ - либа https://github.com/miteshpithadiya/SearchableSpinner , которая решает мою проблему в 2 строчки: добавление зависимости и изменением "Spinner" на "com.toptoche.searchablespinnerlibrary.SearchableSpinner"