# Android ListView обновляется не сразу

Tags: java, android, listview

Я вас категорически приветствую. Решил сделать фильтр для ListView через ввод в EditText.

```
public class ItemListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> { //класс адаптера

    private ArrayList<Item> filteredList;
    private Context context;

    ItemListAdapter(@NonNull ArrayList<Item> filteredList, Context context) {
        super(context, R.layout.track_item, filteredList);
        this.filteredList = filteredList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int pos, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        @SuppressLint("ViewHolder")
        View item = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);

        //код

        return item;
    }

    //сам фильтр
    public void filter(String charText) { 
        charText = charText.toLowerCase();
        filteredList.clear();
        if (charText.length() == 0) {
            filteredList.addAll(MainActivity.orList);
        }
        else {
            for (Item item : MainActivity.orList) {
                if (item.getName().toLowerCase().contains(charText)) {
                    filteredList.add(item);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

ListView находится внутри фрагмента, а EditText в основной активности. Взаимодейтсвие между ними реализовал через интерфейс `ListViewSorter sorter`:

```
sorter = new ListViewSorter() {
    @Override
    public void inputSort(String s) {
        myListAdapter.filter(s); //фильтрую
    }
};
```

`EditText editText`:

```
    editText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if ((keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
                    (i == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {

                //После нажатия ентер пользователем, обращаюсь к интерфейсу
                PlaceholderFragment.sorter.inputSort(editText.getText().toString());

                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Проблема в том, что список обновляется после прямого взаимодействия с ним (нажатие, скроллинг...), хотя должен сразу после фильтрации. `invalidateViews() notifyDataSetChanged() refreshDrawableState()` - ничего из этого не помогает.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1196981/265051

Answer (score 0):

Могу ошибаться но вам нужно повесить не обработчик нажатия на EditText а обработчик изменения текста. Что-то такое :

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

@Override    
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
 int count, int after) {
}

@Override    
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
 int before, int count) {

   PlaceholderFragment.sorter.inputSort(editText.getText().toString());

}
});
```

Comment: У меня стоит обработчик нажатия Enter на виртуальной клавиатуре. Фильтрацию нужно делать после полного ввода, да и через `TextWatcher` приложение крашается в один момент, так что это не совсем то что нужно